# What does shrinkWrap do in the ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter

In the following example, which is making a horizontal list of product cards, a shrinkWrap property was used. Newetherless I did not notice any difference wheither it used or not. So what's actualy the purpose of the shrinkWrap here?

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: products.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ProductCard(product: products[index]);
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` usually fills all the available space of its own parent, without any attention to the minimum size that each item needs. with using `shrinkWrap` and setting it to `true` you can change this scenario so that the `ListView` only occupies the space that each item needs in general. Obviously, if the parent widget does not have the minimum height, it would scroll even if you set `shrinkWrap` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

If you do not set the shrinkWrap property, your ListView will be as big as its parent.

If you set it to true, the list will wrap its content and be as big as it children allows it to be.